# Color of row in longtable

Tags: tables, color, longtable

How to colour only the part between the first and the second line, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ *{9}{r}| *{6}{r} }

\hline
    \rowcolor{Gray}
    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-7pt]
    \rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}  \\
    \rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}  \\
    \rowcolor{Gray}  % <---------------- ??????????????????
    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-7pt]
\hline
     &&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-7pt]
    \endhead
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\
 \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code comes from using `&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-7pt]` in order to increase the distance between text and horizontal lines. Remove all of them and the color says between the two horizontal lines. In order to increase the row heights, I added the `cellspace` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{ *{9}{0r}| *{6}{0r} }
\hline
    \rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1}& \multicolumn{1}{0c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1}  \\
    \rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1}& \multicolumn{1}{0c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{0c}{1}  \\

\hline
    \endhead
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\
 \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an alternative using `longtblr` from `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[caption = {caption},label = {key}]
                {colspec = {*{9}{r}| *{6}{r}}, rowhead = 2, row{1,2}={c,Gray}}
\hline 
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1  \\  
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1  \\ \hline 
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1  \\ \hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It might be simpler to write `row{1,2}={c,Gray}` with `tabularray`.

Comment: @L.J.R.: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my answer accordingly. (Regarding the use of multiple `SetRow{<color>}`  commands: I was inspired by the example code in the beginning of chapter 4 of the tabularray documentation, version 2021L. Adding a remark on that topic there as well, might be useful.)

Comment: Yes, I still need to improve the documentation in many aspects.